# Precedence of yield in EcmaScript 6

Tags: javascript, node.js, yield, ecmascript-harmony, ecmascript-6

I have a function `build` that synchronously returns an object, that in turn contains a function `run`. This function returns a thunk and hence can be called using `yield` and a library such as [`co`](https://github.com/visionmedia/co).

Basically the call looks like this:

```
yield build().run();
```

Now, the problem is that I want to make sure that the `yield` refers to `run`, not to `build`. How do I do that, without introducing a temporary variable as in the following snippet?

```
var temp = build();
yield temp.run();
```

Any ideas?

PS: I'm running this code on Node.js 0.11.x using the ´--harmony´ flag.

Comment: Little has higher precedence over the member operator and the call operator, so you're safe. Here's a reference for you [MDN Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). The `yield` is pretty far down there. Are you having an issue where it isn't working as you expect?

Comment: Well, I was wondering how to distinguish this from the case where I would want to call `build` using `yield` in case this was the thunkified function. Would that then be `(yield build()).run()`?

Comment: Yes, you'd need the explicit grouping in that case.

Comment: Great :-)). Thanks for your hint, this perfectly helped me. If you turn your comments into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Little has higher precedence over the member operator and the call operator, so you're safe. Here's a reference for you [MDN Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). The `yield` is pretty far down there.

If you wanted to group `yield` to the `build()` call, you'd need an explicit grouping.

```
(yield build()).run()
```